# Marshal XML sub-element under root with Go

Tags: xml, go

is there a way to marshal XML in the following example such that the sub-elements under `MyElement` are marshaled under the root `MyXML` as follows:

```
type MyXML struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"myXML"`
    Element *MyElement `xml:",any"`
}

type MyElement struct {
    A string `xml:"a"`
    B string `xml:"b"`
    C string `xml:"c"`
}
```

I’d like the following result:

```
<myXML>
    <a>blah</a>
    <b>blah</b>
    <c>blah</c>
</myXML>
```

If I marshal as is I get:

```
<myXML>
    <Element>
        <a>blah</a>
        <b>blah</b>
        <c>blah</c>
    </Element>
</myXML>
```

Is this possible by way of implementing the xml.Marshaler interface via the MyElement struct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `XMLName` field of type `xml.Name` on a struct to marshal it to the name you'd like.

```
type MyXML struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"myXML"`
    A       string   `xml:"a"`
    B       string   `xml:"b"`
    C       string   `xml:"c"`
}

func main() {
    testXML := MyXML{
        A: "test a",
        B: "test b",
        C: "test c",
    }
    xmlBytes, err := xml.Marshal(testXML)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error parsing xml: %s", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(string(xmlBytes))
}
```

[This example on Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/jC5m_mtcut)

Comment: Thanks MahlerFive. That I understand. But in my scenario, my A, B and C elements reside underneath a catch-all (`xml:”,any”`) MyElement type and not directly under the root myXML. So not sure how to hoist those elements.

Comment: Why do you need the `MyElement` type at all? I guess I'm not understanding.

Comment: Trying to avoid having to duplicate those same A, B and C properties for other structs that require MyElement. I also need to marshal MyElement to JSON, which is semantically different than the XML.